# XML Schema: exclude HTML entities and control characters from strings

Tags: xml, xsd, html-entities, control-characters

Is there an XSD datatype that excludes HTML entities and other control characters from a string in an XML instance?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in XSD data type that excludes HTML character entities or control characters, but you may not need one anyway because XML's laws of well-formedness ***already preclude***

1. Character entities that are not defined in the document and are not
   [predefined](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent):

   > ```
   > <!ENTITY lt     "&#38;#60;">
   > <!ENTITY gt     "&#62;">
   > <!ENTITY amp    "&#38;#38;">
   > <!ENTITY apos   "&#39;">
   > <!ENTITY quot   "&#34;">
   > ```
2. [Unicode characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) in the surrogate blocks, FFEE, and FFFF, which are not allowed by this production:

   > ```
   > Char::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF]|[#xE000-#xFFFD]|[#x10000-#x10FFFF]
   > ```

Should you still wish to exclude additional characters, you can define a type that restricts `xs:string` to, say, exclude the [Unicode general category](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values) *Other* category, which will exclude all of the following categories:

> ```
> C Other   Cc | Cf | Cs | Co | Cn
> Cc    Control a C0 or C1 control code
> Cf    Format  a format control character
> Cs    Surrogate   a surrogate code point
> Co    Private_Use a private-use character
> Cn    Unassigned  a reserved unassigned code point or a noncharacter
> ```

via this XSD type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="NoUnicodeOtherCodePointsString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[\P{C}]*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I think you meant to negate the class in the pattern like so: `<xs:pattern value="[^\P{C}]*"/>`. Also, this doesn't have anything to do with the ASCII character set or not much to do with the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block.

Comment: @TomBlodget: You'd be right had I written lowercase `\p{C}`, but uppercase `\P{C}` is correct to allow "printable" characters only.  If you'd care to suggest a better name than *`ASCIIprintableString`*, I'd be happy to take that suggestion, provided the name doesn't imply that I have to explicitly state some long list of characters.  :-)  Thank you.

Comment: @TomBlodget: Sure, thanks for the nudge to improve the name of the restricted string type.  Answer updated with a better type name and explanation of `\P{C}`.  Thank you.